# how to do Segue from external view in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using a library that opens up a view the shows on top of your current view.
when this view is finished, i'm getting a callback, 
and i wrote a performSegue in it, to the next screen.

in the storyboard, i connected my View to the destination view i want to reach

but when i call the perform Segue, after the library View has closed
i get an error

```
Error connecting to remote view
```

am i doing something wrong ?
how would i call a segue
differently ?

this is what i'm doing:

```
func visitDidComplete(_ visitSuccessful: Bool, with reason: AWSDKVisitEndReason) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "summeryScreenSeg", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

and in the storyboard

[image]

Thnx.

Comment: Share your code, how you call performSegue?

Comment: Would be great if you could share some relevant snippets of your code in order to add some context

Comment: @Andrew i shared the code